# Best way to bind directly to objects returned from a web service

Tags: silverlight, web-services, silverlight-4.0

In silverlight 3 I had an object that had a property that was an observable collection.  I returned this via a web service then databinded to it.

Upgrade to silveright 4.....

Now my program crashes because the Observable Collection is converted to an array.

What is the best way to do this?  Observable collection is not even an option any longer.

Comment: ObservableCollections are still there.  I just used one ten minutes ago.  Could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'Service Reference' configuration under 'Advanced' is the 'Dictionary collection type' set to 'Array'?